# Video, uploaded on S3 bucket, not playing through url in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, post

I am uploading the videos and images on S3 bucket through the post request to s3 service (without using AWS SDK). The images and videos are uploaded successfully. But the video is not playing from its url.

Below is the error that is printed on the console:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3url}

Following is the code for the multipart request that I am using:

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in
        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                multiPart.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
        print("mime type ==================>\(mimeType)")
        //mime type for video: "video/mp4"
        multiPart.append(file, withName: key, fileName: fileName, mimeType: mimeType)
    }, usingThreshold: 10000, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                print("response string")
                print(response)
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print(response.result.isSuccess)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(self.parseError(error: error))
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the video files available publicly? if you put the URL in the browser does it open?

Comment: @Scriptable yes all the files have public access. If I open the url in browser, then the file is getting downloaded and then after adding the .mov extension to the file, it gets played in the Quick time player.

Comment: can you show the code where you try to play it?

Comment: I am playing it through a third party library VGPlayer. But I also tried it on AVPlayerController, it does not work.

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this was that while uploading the video, the Content-Type for video was not setting due to which the video was not playing. Setting the Content-Type in form-data as well as in Policy, the video uploaded and played successfully.

Comment: can you please check my question for same error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65229124/corrected-video-uploaded-in-s3-servers-using-alamofire

Comment: @S.V can you develop the answer on how to set it up?